# Create custom view in custom lib get error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I need to create a custom view in lib. My code:
Custom view in custom lib(in project which have one class(is the view)):

```
public class PagingHTMLView extends SurfaceView {

    public PagingHTMLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public PagingHTMLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PagingHTMLView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

}
```

I create test project and right click to test project =>build path=>Configure build path=>select Projects tab and select lib project.
I create a activity in test project:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PagingHTMLView p=new PagingHTMLView(this);
        p.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        RelativeLayout l=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        l.addView(p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.inazaruk.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/layout">


</RelativeLayout>
```

and get error:

```
06-09 13:52:09.181: E/AndroidRuntime(265): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: theTG.race.PagingHTMLView.PagingHTMLView
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.example.testhtmlview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-09 13:52:09.200: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if in test project I create activity with code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.inazaruk.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <theTG.race.PagingHTMLView.PagingHTMLView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get error:

```
06-09 14:08:33.080: E/AndroidRuntime(290): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testhtmlview/com.example.testhtmlview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class theTG.race.PagingHTMLView.PagingHTMLView
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class theTG.race.PagingHTMLView.PagingHTMLView
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at com.example.testhtmlview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  ... 11 more
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: theTG.race.PagingHTMLView.PagingHTMLView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43b869c0
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
06-09 14:08:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(290):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: did you try cleaning up the project and running it again?

Comment: I just clean project and rerun. It don't solve my problem.(I don't know how to build lib project-when I run test project then lib project auto build)